# how to get progress report from ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

I have a `List<MyClass>` with a N numbers of items. I process with the following code

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWorkWithItem, item);
}

private void DoWorkWithItem(object threadContext)
{
   ///...
}
```

but i need get report what item was proccessed, where i can get a Event or something for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create event and call it after threat iteration finished, like this:

```
public class ClassWithDelegate
{
    public delegate void ProgressReportEventHandler();
    public static ProgressReportEventHandler ProgressReport { get; set; };

    private void DoWorkWithItem(object threadContext)
    {
       // angry code

       if (ProgressReport != null)
          ProgressReport();
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
         ClassWithDelegate.ProgressReport += ProgressReport;         
    }

    public void ProgressReport()
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

or use `BackgroundWorker`, it has this event

Comment: It's important to note that ProgressReport will be called from a background (thread pool) thread.  In all liklihood your progress will need to show up on a UI in some way, in which case you will have to marshal UI changes back to the UI thread with things like WinForms Control.BeginInvoke or WPF's/Silverlight's Dispatcher.